# Getting all spans that contain [name]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve and loop through all the elements on my page which are spans and have name tag. Any ideas?

```
$("span[name$='*']").each(function () {  // first pass, create name mapping               
           // Console.log(this);
            //name_map[name] = (name_map[name]) ? name + "[]" : name;
 });

<span class="col-xs-2 control-label" name="toddler">xxx</span> <-- get this
<span class="col-xs-2 control-label">xxx</span> <-- don't get this
```

Comment: `$("span[name]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = $("span[name]").map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get();


console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="col-xs-2 control-label" name="toddler">xxx1</span>
<span class="col-xs-2 control-label">xxx</span>
```

1. use only `$('span[name]')`. Means Span with name attribute

Comment: If you want to use pure JavaScript you can use

`document.querySelectorAll('span[name]');`

Comment: @guradio Any ideas how to serialize these values?

Comment: @alwaysVBNET yo serialize you can use `.serialize();` but it needs name and value. and value is not valid attribute for span.. you need to use `input`. Or you can just create it yourself

Answer (score 4):

You can just put the attribute in the selector with no value, eg `[name]`. Try this:

```js
$("span[name]").addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="col-xs-2 control-label" name="toddler">yes</span>
<span class="col-xs-2 control-label">no</span>
```